# Rad Studio 10 and Mac OSX Sierra (virtualbox guest)

Tags: iphone, windows, macos, delphi, virtualbox

Since i started developping applications using Rad Studio 10 i'm able to test the windows and android versions on my desktop. 
However, i do not have a Mac. So i decide to create a virtualbox guest Mac OSX Sierra on my Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. It works fine but i'm not able to connect and share files between Mac/Windows or test iPhone using Rad Studio.

What steps do it requires to configure my virtualbox to work with RAD Studio 10 ?

Comment: I hope you are aware of the fact that this is not allowed (running macOS on a not-Mac)?

Comment: You can't possibly expect to deploy a Mac version of your software without actually testing it on an actual Mac computer.  There are major differences running on the actual computer rather than a VM. Doing so is like saying *I'm going to sell my self-driving car. It works on a computer, but I'm not going to bother building an actual prototype and seeing if it can drive itself. The computer says it will work. Let's produce a few thousand of them now.* Also attempting to do so is  violation of Apple's licensing terms, and EMBT's documentation says that an actual Mac OS is required.

Comment: guy, stop one minute, if you want to buy a mac, buy a mac ! Now gave me ONE exemple (just one in the world of millions of developpers)  where someone was in trouble because he use a virtual machine to run a mac with the objective to produce an app that he will put in the app store where apple will win money (at least 30% of the incomes) thanks to it ! just one example ... so don't say anything about licence, it's ridiculous and will never success in front of any judge ..

Comment: @KenWhite : he was speaking about ios not mac !

Comment: @loki: iOS and Mac are the same (Apple products), and iOS requires a Mac license. If you object, talk to Apple about their licensing, not me. **Apple** says that to develop for iOS you must have a Mac, and since both are Apple OSes and iPhones and iPads are Apple products,  it's their decision and not mine or yours. (And the question title says **OSX**. Check your reading skills.)

Comment: @KenWhite yes and ? i repeat you don't need a mac, a virtual machine is enalf, and it's not because apple say that it's forbidden in their licence that it's will not work nor that you will have any problem with apple ...

Comment: @loki: Apple has been known to go after people in the past. Regardless of your opinions on the matter, Apple's license says a Mac is required; that is a fact, whether you like it or not. If you want to discuss it further, you can find Apple at http://apple.com. I'm not them, and neither is Stack Overflow. Discuss it with them, not me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lucky if virtual box work fine, me i always have trouble with it (especially connecting the ios device). However i found that vmware is much more stable, full screen resolution, much (much) better to handle the iphone connection via usb, and i didn't have yet any crash when on virtual box it's quite often

on vmware, you can also copy/past text from the virtual machine to the host that is very usefull when debuging (on virtual box you can not)

on both (vmware and virtual box) you need to setup the connection as bridged connection. after you successful installed the emb pa server, you can get the ip of the machine with the command "i"